# What is the best replacement for a gallery in Android?

Tags: android

I need to implement a gallery of clickable images that can be scrolled horizontally, and the *Gallery* widget is deprecated. What is the best replacement?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ImageView` which will scroll in horizontally on swipe.For the swipe you can use `onFling()` method where you can handle left and right swipe.Read this post for gesture [detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a custom horizontal listview (by Paul Soucy from dev-smart.com)
https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView

Comment: this one is good enough if you don't need the center-locking feature of the gallery widget

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I eventually decided to use gallery widget because i needed the center-locking feature. (I just don't really understand what are the results of using something that is deprecated)

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Comment: https://github.com/gaowen/Android-Horizontal-ListView

Answer (score 1):

Use [DevsmartLib-Android](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android). Also, if you don't care about the flinging, you can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Answer (score 0):

This one is much better: https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Good Luck!